# How to display a status message as different Excel macros are called?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button which updates a pivot table and calls 3 different excel macros which perform large data updates. I would like to display an update message between each macro to let the user know which piece of data is being updated.

```
Sub Button11_Click()
'Update Volumes
    Set pt = Sheets("PRE Vol. Data").PivotTables("PRE Volumes")
With pt
    .RefreshTable
End With
'Update Uniformance
    Call PullUniformanceData
'Update All Pad Data
    Call FillDowntoDate_Click
'Update OE Line Data
    Call FillDowntoDateLineData_Click
End Sub
```

Can a UserForm be used to provide updates? I would like the update to read "Updating Step 1/4".

Comment: There are a lot of examples out there on the internet tbh.

Comment: To answer your question, yes a `vbModeless` userform can be up while other code is running, which can be updated via triggers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Button11_Click()
   'Update Volumes
    Set pt = Sheets("PRE Vol. Data").PivotTables("PRE Volumes")
    With pt
      .RefreshTable
    End With
    UpdateMessage("Refresh table complete")

    'Update Uniformance
     Call PullUniformanceData
     UpdateMessage("Uniformance Data Complete")

    'Update All Pad Data
     Call FillDowntoDate_Click
     UpdateMessage("DowntoDate complete")
    'Update OE Line Data
     Call FillDowntoDateLineData_Click
     UpdateMessage("DowntoDateLine Data Complete")

     UpdateMessage("All Macros completed")
End Sub

Sub UpdateMessage(strMessage As String)
    ''assuming you have form "frmMain"setup with a text box
    frmMain.txtStatus.Caption = strMessage

    '' If you dont have a form, then use a cell that you prefer
    set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'update here the sheet you want to show
    set loc = ws.cells(1,1)' update here to point to the cell you want the message to show

    loc.Value = strMessage
    DoEvents ' dont forget this call

End Sub
```